# Upgrade to Angular 9 white screen when navigating to build

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I recently upgraded angular from 8 to 9 and everything works when using ng serve.

When building my project it builds fine without any errors. Once I serve it and navigate to localhost:4000 all I get back is a white page. I don't see any errors in my console or any warnings.

If I type /index.html at the end of localhost:4000 I'm able to get to my landing page and navigate the site. I did not have to do this before upgrading to angular 9. I'm a bit at a loss as to what it could be I've already spent a day on this thinking maybe it's an issue with a node module and trying to make changes to my server.ts. I have not had much luck.

What could cause this sort of issue? and is there any easy way to go about debugging this issue?

I'll share my server.ts file here

```js
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import { enableProdMode }   from '@angular/core';
import { ngExpressEngine }  from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
import { join }             from 'path';

import * as express     from 'express';
import * as compression from 'compression';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

// compress all responses
app.use(compression());

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./server/main');

// Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// The /health path is used as a health check in Cloudflare
// to check the status of the node process.
app.get('/health', (req, res) => { res.send('HEALTHY'); });

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', (req, res, next) => {
  next();
}, express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'), { maxAge: '1y', fallthrough: false }));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  next();
}, (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req }, (err, html) => {
    res.send(html);
  });
});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack);
  next(err);
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```